# PostgreSQL — measure logical replication lag

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-11

Is there a way to measure *logical* replication lag in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check `pg_catalog.pg_replication_slots`. Run this code on the **master** (**publisher**) server:

```
SELECT 
    slot_name,
    confirmed_flush_lsn, 
    pg_current_wal_lsn(), 
    (pg_current_wal_lsn() - confirmed_flush_lsn) AS lsn_distance
FROM pg_replication_slots;
```

`lsn_distance` is the measure of the replication lag.

Comment: FWIW, this appears to have been discussed here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CY1PR17MB04587C36946F2C2BBA45B2B3DA560%40CY1PR17MB0458.namprd17.prod.outlook.com. I just almost created a Q&A identical to this one for my own work. Thank you!

Comment: what is the unit of this lag? Byte?

Comment: `lsn_distance` is measured in bytes, because it's the difference between two [pg_lsn](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/datatype-pg-lsn.html) numbers: 

"Two LSNs can be subtracted using the - operator; the result is the number of bytes separating those write-ahead log locations."